# Scala Future Type mismatch issue

Tags: scala, future

I am running into an issue with Scala and multiple futures in a for yield scenario.  Both f1 and f2 are futures.  f2 future is based on a value obtained from f1 future.

```
val result = for {
    f1 <- Await.result(dao.findNode("nodeA"), 5 seconds)            // This returns back a MyNode class
    f2 <- if (f1 != None && f1.isUpAndRunning)
                Future { LookupResult(true, f1.varA, f1.varB) }
          else
                lk ? Lookup(sm.id, sm.("address"))
} yield(f1, f2)
```

Dependent on the result of f1 I either do a Lookup() when my if statement evaluates to false (which takes some time and returns back a LookupResult) or I mimic a default LookupResult.

Getting the following error back:

Type mismatch. Required: Option[B_], found: Future[(MyNode, Any)]

Am I just not mapping the result correctly?  e.g. should I use asInstanceOf somewhere as whatever I do I cannot get this to compile.

Many thanks guys.

Comment: The `Await.result` in the middle of a future `for`-comprehension looks suspicious, and it's unclear in what context `f1 != None && f1.isUpAndRunning` could be meaningful. Unclear what you're asking, too much of a context is missing. Please provide a minimal isolated example that produces a compilation error that is similar to what you're trying to resolve.

Comment: Strictly speaking `for` comprehensions are supposed to used over the same `Monad`. `Await.result` give you an `Option[A]` (so `Option` monad. Your `if` case gives you back a `Future[B]`, so `Future` monad. I don't know what your else branch is giving you, but just looking at `f1` and `if` case of `f2`, you should be able to see that you are comprehending over an `Option` and then `Future`, so why do expect it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your `dao.findNode` method results in a `Future[Option[MyNode]]`, so the `Await.result` makes `f1` an `Option[MyNode]`.  It's not that clear what type you want, but you can get a `Future[(Option[MyNode], LookupResult)]` with this

```scala
dao.findNode("nodeA"), 5.seconds)
  .flatMap { nodeOpt: Option[MyNode] =>
    nodeOpt.filter(_.isUpAndRunning)
      .map { node =>
        // node exists and is up and running
        val finalResult = nodeOpt -> LookupResult(true, node.varA, node.varB)

        // it's much more efficient in this scenario to use
        // Future.successful than Future { }
        Future.successful(finalResult)
      }
      .getOrElse {
        // node didn't exist, or wasn't up and running
        val lookupFut = lk ? Lookup(sm.id, sm.("address"))
        lookupFut.map { lookupResult =>
          nodeOpt -> lookupResult
        }
      }
  }
```

The rough outline of what's happening is:

- use `dao` to find the node
- schedule a callback for when we get the (possibly nonexistent) node to check if it's up and running (in which case we short-circuit to our now-known final result), otherwise perform the lookup and build a final result if that lookup succeeds

`Future.successful` is used because `Future {}` will almost certainly incur more overhead scheduling a task on a thread and completing the future than constructing the final result.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're looking for, or if you've got some bizarre (and probably ill-advised) implicits in scope monkeying with the types.